# Can't uninstall ASP.NET on Windows Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

Running `aspnet_regiis -i` on Windows Server 2012 doesn't work, so I need to uninstall/reinstall ASP.NET 4.5. However, I don't seem to be able to do so because the options are greyed out in the "Add Roles and Features Wizard". How can I uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 and re-install?

[image]

Comment: Is it 32 or 64 bit? Also is it net 4.5 or 4.5.1?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Server 2012 R2

1. Server Manger
2. Manage
3. Remove Roles and Features

This will bring up the **Uninstall-only** version of the GUI in your screenshot.

[Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831809(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_removerrfw) containing alternative approaches (such as PowerShell).

Answer (score 0):

You will find a list of commands on the link below just opt for the silent uninstall command for your version of Windows and. Net

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/04/16/9553804.aspx